# Next-Auth Session Synchronization Among Tabs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

I've implemented authentication using next-auth on a Next.js application. I've used OAuth with Google. The signIn and signOut behaviour works as expected. However, when I logged out from Google in another application, for example Gmail, my application still stays logged in.

Is is possible to synchronize the session among applications?

Comment: Were you able to find any leads?